# Squashed search bar in mobile view

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I have the following search bar and when viewing it on the mobile phone, it is getting squashed. Any idea how I can fix that please?

```
<div id="menu" class="py-4 d-flex justify-content-center">
            <div class="row ">
                <div class="col-sm-auto ">


                    <div class="input-group">
                    <span style="color:black" class="input-group-addon form-control">
                    <select id="selection" onchange="getValues(this.value)">
                        <option>Choose Category</option>
                        <option>Notary</option>
                        <option>Deed Date</option>
                        <option>Person</option>
                        <option>Place</option>
                        <option>Manuscript Reference</option>
                        <option>Subject</option>
                    </select>
                    </span>
                        <input id="search" type="text" class="form-control" name="search" placeholder="Choose a category" disabled=true>
                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="searchButton" onclick="doSparql(this.value)"   style="border-width: 1px; border-color: lightgray;"><span class="fa fa-search"></span></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you should change style in mobile size, like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  // style in mobile size, for example show select and span in two line
}
```

Comment: Can't I make it shrink according to the size of the screen instead of two lines?

Comment: you should show them in two line text or reduce font-size or other element size. but this is not good, because in mobile size, size of buttons and other clickable element can be touch with a finger.

Comment: can you kindly show me an example of your solution...what should I write in the comment section?

Comment: can i see you your code? i dont know how you style it?
for example : #selection {display: block}